# PhpStorm and SCSS compile scss file into one css file

Tags: sass, ide, phpstorm

I'm taking my first steps in PhpStorm and SASS. I went to File > Settings > File Watcher and I added SCSS

This is my current configuration:

- Program: `C:\Ruby23\bin\scss.bat`
- Arguments: `--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`
- Working directory: `$FileDir$`
- Output paths to refresh: `$FileParentDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

And it's working in the following way. Given the structure:

```
/mysite
    /sass
        1.scss
        2.scss
        3.scss
```

when I add a SCSS file to `/sass` it generates `.css` and `.css.map` files inside `/mysite`. However, I want to generate just one CSS file inside `/mysite` and avoid the map files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. if you have a primary SCSS file that imports other files (partials, their names usually start with underscore), you just need to make sure that '`Track only root files`' is enabled in File watcher settings to get the output merged into a single .css
2. If you don't like `.map` files being created, pass `--sourcemap=none` to compiler

Comment: Thanks a lot, @lena. Works perfect! You made my day =)

Comment: @lena Any idea hot to autoprefix SCSS files output in phpstorm?